# Show button in DataView row on mouseover (ExtJS)

Tags: extjs, mouseover, dataview

I would like to show a (delete) button in a DataView row in ExtJS. I don't want the delete button to be always visible but just on a mouseover.

If anyone has an example that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side note, a DataView doesn't necessarily have "rows".  It has whatever you want it to have, depending on the XTemplate given to it.

Having said that, you can add the `overCls` config option to your DataView, and that class will be added to the view's items when the mouse hovers over it.  Then it's just a matter of using CSS to show or hide the delete button based on the existence of the overCls.

```
new Ext.DataView({
    tpl: '<tpl for=".">' +
            '<div class="my-wrapper">' +
                '<div class="my-close-button">X</div>' +
                // ... normal content
            '</div>' +
         '</tpl>',
    overCls: 'my-wrapper-hover',
    itemSelector: 'div.my-wrapper',
    ...
})
```

Then in CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .my-wrapper .my-close-button { display: none; }
    .my-wrapper-hover .my-close-button { display: block !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, small addition when using the dataview to display a list: use the overClass instead of the overCls for list entry specific style.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, if you want to have the same functionality in a GridPanel (v3.3 tested), it can be achieved with a slight variation on the above.

```
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
      //grid config...
      columns: [{
            header   : 'Actions',
            xtype    : 'actioncolumn',
                items    : [{
                icon   : '../images/delete16.gif',
                iconCls: 'my-close-button',

                //..the rest of your config...
    });

grid.getView().rowOverCls="my-wrapper-hover";
```

The css is exactly as specified above.